# How can I restore a deleted object in TYPO3?

Tags: repository, typo3-6.2.x

I am using a command controller to import a car list. Now I want to set all the cars which already exists into TYPO3 database to 
**deleted = 1** before I start the import. After that I want to update only the cars which are on the import list, but this is working only if I run the import command twice and I don't know why.

My importCommand looks as follows:

```
/**
 * import command
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function importCommand() {

    // get all cars from repository
    $currentCars = $this->carRepository->findAll();

    foreach ($currentCars as $car) {
        // mark all cars as deleted
        $this->carRepository->remove($car);
    }

    ... read list and store imported data into cars array

    foreach ($this->cars as $car) {

        // check if car exists
        if (!$this->carRepository->exists($car[1])) {

            $carObject = $this->objectManager->get(
                'Fox\\Example\\Domain\\Model\\Car'
            );

            $this->carExists = false;

        } else {

            $carObject = $this->carRepository->getCarByGroupId($car[1])[0];

            $this->carExists = true;

        }

        ... set car properties

        if (!$this->carExists) {
            $this->carRepository->add($carObject);
        } else {
            $carObject->setDeleted(0);
            $this->carRepository->update($carObject);
        }

    }

}
```

If I run the command controller via shell and then looking into phpmyadmin I can see that the cars will be updated when I run the import command, but the property **deleted** will be only updated if I run the import command twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're producing lot of overheat imho... i.e. you can mark all cars with common [TYPO3 DB API](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_database_1_1_database_connection.html) which works ok even in Extbase repository:

```php
// Delete all
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_DELETEquery('tx_example_domain_model_car', '1');

// Restore all
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery('tx_example_domain_model_car', 'deleted=1', array('deleted' => 0));
```

On the other hand you definitely should **NOT** use the `deleted` field to do this! Instead create a boolean field like `hiddenBeforeImport` and modify your `exists(...)` method and set this to true instead removing items, reason is simple, soon you'll not be able to recognize which car is deleted because it was deleted before import, and which is deleted, because somebody clicked thrash icon in the BE. Of course also with custom field DB API methods will be more effective over the Extbase's iteration.

Comment: Ok thanks. The BE is not so important, because a user can only manipulate some fields which will not be imported and only effect the frontend. I think the deleted field is right for this job, because it marks objects as deleted or as not deleted. So if an object was deleted from the list then it is not needed anymore in TYPO3 and should be marked as deleted.